# Convert "polygon((" to GeoJSON

Tags: file, polygon, geojson

i´m trying to convert a file which i exported from openJUMP to GeoJSON.
For example:

```
POLYGON((6.09836816787714 51.96887588500988, 6.098301887512321 51.96438980102539,
         6.0997509956359295 51.96348190307623, 6.099466800689811 51.9437370300293, 
         6.099460124969539 51.94330596923828, 6.099398136138973 51.939044952392635,    
         6.099389076232853 51.93835067749035, 6.099374771118278 51.93745422363287, 
         6.099363803863639 51.93655395507824, 6.099881172180176 51.93453598022472)
```

(shorted example). When i convert it per hand, everything is fine and it works. But there are ~ 50 Polygons and maybe its possible to convert them automatically? How is the filetype called?

Comment: First step in writing a conversion script is what does your input look like? (as in the question ... looks simple) what do you want the output to look like?

Comment: Hi Simson, the input-file looks like a list of the given example. This is the full list: http://pastebin.com/bjPaxBpK . I need a Geo-JSON File like specified here: http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#id4 .

Comment: I think you should try to write a parser in perl for this. A while loop to read the file - make sure every POLYGON is read as one then split it if there are inner or outer parenthesis. (i.e a hole in the shape) for every line print it in the new format.

Comment: @LuisFFCavalcante posted a useful answer but somehow it was deleted by another user so I copy the post here "You can use this tool: https://rodic.fr/blog/online-conversion-between-geometric-formats/"